# How to know if optional template parameter was not given?

Tags: c++, c++11, templates

Is is possible to know if an optional template parameter was not given/set? Made an attempt with std::is_empty to no avail.

```
template<class T, class U = int> 
class A {
    public:
        T x;
        U y;
  
        void check() { 
            if (std::is_empty<U>::value)
                std::cout << "not given\n";
            else
                std::cout << "given\n";
        }
};

int main()
{
    A<float> a(1.5);    
    a.check();
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't `U` be an `int` in your example? That can't be an empty type

Comment: But if it's not given, then what is it? T was given (float), but not U as it is optional. Well, I suppose it was given by default, but if U was given another type, then how?

Comment: @Ender -- yes, it's given **by the default**. That's what `= int` means in the declaration. And you can't distinguish between using the default by not specifying the second type and specifying the second type as `int`. That is, `A<float>` and `A<float, int>` mean exactly the same thing.

Comment: Maybe a bit of clarification is needed: `U` is **not optional**; it is required by the definition of the template. At the point where the template is **used** the type doesn't have to be specified, because it has a **default** type.

Answer (score 4):

If it is not supplied by the user, it is `int`:

```
template<class T, class U = int> 
                          ^^^^^
```

that is what `= int` means.

There is no way to tell within the template if `int` was passed explicitly or if it was set implicitly by skipping it.

You can make `A<float>` different from `A<float, int>` in a number of ways.

You could `U = void` then set `RealU` within the template to `U` unless it is void, and `int` if it is void.

You could take `class...U` and restrict your code to `sizeof...(U)<=1`.  Then do the same `RealU` trick.

You could make a wrapper template that does this stuff, and have the real template get passed `T`, `U` and a `bool` saying if `U` was passed.

In every case, the type of `A<float>` will not match the type of `A<float, int>` because you are implicitly demanding that to be the case.